# Can't access methods/variables in a different classes

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get the body of this link to be stored in String HTML and then load it to the WebView. (Parsing the code is done with Jsoup). When I press the button, the debugger shows me **String HTML = re.fixCode();** and says "Debug Current Instruction Pointer".

I have tried many things, like passing the string in a method and passing the string as it. But the same thing happens over and over. My conclusion is that it doesn't pass the method/variables to my other classes? (Hope you understand that last bit)

And if that is the case how do I access them? Through intents?

So to be clear, I want to get the body, pass it on to a string and then load it in the WebView. Thanks!

Main class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private String uri = "http://www.novasoftware.se/webviewer/%28S%28muz0tu55twfd43zkqrlejb55%29%29/design1.aspx?schoolid=18200&code=83310";
    private RequestTask re;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        WebSettings webSettings = web.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);



        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new RequestTask().execute(uri);
                loadWeb();
            }
        });

    }

    private void loadWeb() {
        **String HTML = re.fixCode();**
        System.out.println(HTML);
        //      web.loadData(re.fixedHtml, "text/html", null);
    }
}
```

RequestTask class

```
package com.dir.schema;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    public String html, fixedHtml;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        String responseString = null;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                out.close();
                responseString = out.toString();
            } else{
                //Closes the connection.
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            //TODO Handle problems..
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //TODO Handle problems..
        }
        return responseString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //Do anything with response..
        html = result;
        fixCode();
    }

    public String fixCode() {
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        return fixedHtml = doc.body().toString();

    }

    }
```

Comment: Do you get an actual error? If so, what is it? If it's an NPE, is `doc` or `doc.body()` `null`? If not, are you sure you didn't just inadvertently set a breakpoint there?

Comment: @JasonC It is not and NPE doc and doc.body() has a value, I checked.
when I run it, it says "This kind of launch is configuration to open the Dubug perspective when suspended"

Answer (score 0):

You're calling **re.fixCode()**, but **re** hasn't been set to anything. I expect you're getting a null pointer error at this point.

I think you want to rewrite your **onClick()** method like so:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    re = new RequestTask();
    re.execute(uri);
    loadWeb();
}
```

Comment: Note: I'm going to assume you've got your potential race conditions under control? I think it's likely that **loadWeb()** will be called before your **RequestTask** has finished executing. Will that be a problem?

Comment: yes that might be the problem. How do I solv it? By doing a Thread and then sleep(1000) and let the RequestTask finish?

Comment: Call loadWeb() from onPostExecute() will probably do the trick. Sleeping is never a good idea when trying to avoid race conditions, especially where the internet is concerned.